# What is the meaning of the title, "Dorohedoro"?

Tags: japanese-language, dorohedoro

I just finished watching *Dorohedoro* and loved it, but I am confused as to what the title means exactly?

I searched Google to see what it meant and something comes up saying "doro" means "mud", and "hedo" means "vomit" or "nausea", but then what about the "ro"? So I looked into it a bit further and noticed that the characters used to write the word *Dorohedoro* in Japanese (ドロヘドロ) uses the character for "mud" then "He" then "mud" again.

Seeing as mud can mean earth, does this mean the title is referring to something like the two worlds (the wizard's realm and the hole) touching or being connected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The most probable meaning of the title *Dorohedoro* is "mud-sludge"**, which is consisted of [*doro*](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B3%A5) (mud) and [*hedoro*](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%98%E3%83%89%E3%83%AD) (sludge).

This is referred to in volume 10, chapter 56 of the manga (not yet covered in the anime) when Ai ...

> recalled his experience after jumping into the lake,
>
>  [image: vol. 10, ch. 56, pg. 22]
>
>  "When I fell into the lake, and **mud** (*doro*) and smelly **sludge** (*hedoro*) coiled around me, it felt as if I had become this warped city itself."